# convert ajax response into a particular format?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awCd4.png)    Input: `var result= JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(result);`

Given below is the output of console.log(result); Now i want to convert this into given below output i want like this.

```
Output:     
  {day: Array(7), amount: Array(7)}
  amount: (7) [413, 14, 2, 37, 50, 22, 82]
  day: (7) ["02-Jan-16", "03-Jan-16", "04-Jan-16", "05-Jan-16", "06-Jan-16", 
  "07-Jan-16", "08-Jan-16"]


 This input is ajax response data. Now i  want to convert this response data 
 into a particular format which i describe below. My output should look like 
 this. How can i do this?


 Output I want:

 [[02-Jan-16,413],[03-Jan-16,14],[04-Jan-16,2],[05-Jan-16,37], [06-Jan-
 16,50],[07-Jan-16,22],[08-Jan-16,82]]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWCZv.png)
This is the output image. check it out.

Comment: please add the raw string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the wanted values for a new array.

```js
function getData(object) {
    return data.amount.map(function(a, i) {
        return [object.day[i], a];
    });
}

var data = {
        amount: [413, 14, 2, 37, 50, 22, 82],
        day: ["02-Jan-16", "03-Jan-16", "04-Jan-16", "05-Jan-16", "06-Jan-16", "07-Jan-16", "08-Jan-16"]
    },
    result = getData(data);
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: In this you are defining data statically. I have this data in ajax response object. Now how to convert this.

Comment: you could put the functionality into a function and call it if necessary.

Comment: Here it is for particular data format. Here You know the key. I don't want my code specific to this key like day. If i fetch data in which key is different depend on database then it not working.

Comment: please add the structure of the response and which keys or parts of the keys are known.

Comment: structure of response data is output i write.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to decide in which language you want to do the json coding PHP or JavaScript? There are inbuilt functions available in both the languages, first you should be comfortable with Nested Array, once you understand the Array construction then its just a few minutes job to form expected JSON format using inbuilt functions.

Please don't expect code from us when already plenty of information is available on web, just google it.